# Register schema operation failed while writing to the Kafka store [50001] (with documentation example)

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I'm getting the above error while trying to register the schema in the confluent documentation (via the REST endpoint):

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" --data '{"schema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"Payment\",\"namespace\":\"io.confluent.examples.clients.basicavro\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"id\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"amount\",\"type\":\"double\"}]}"}' http://localhost:8081/subjects/test-value/versions
```

Example can be found here:
https://docs.confluent.io/5.4.0/schema-registry/schema_registry_tutorial.html

Under the section **Auto Schema Registration**

The schema registry was installed via the `helm` charts and is version **5.4.0**

Any help greatly appreciated

**LOGS**

`Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.exceptions.SchemaRegistryStoreException: Error while registering the schema due to generating an ID that is already in use`

Comment: Could you provide any logs?

Comment: Updated. Mind you this is a brand new schema registry with nothing in it so I don't understand how there could be a duplicate of anything

Comment: How did you ensure that the schema registry is empty?

Comment: I cloned the helm charts and built it from there